# How to allow one element or another choice of elements in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Suppose that I have a  `<scene>` element which can contain the following elements:

- `<episode>` and/or `<season>`
- OR `<part>`

Some examples:

```
<scene>
  <part></part>
</scene>
```

Another example:

```
<scene>
 <episode></episode>
 <episode></episode>
 <season></season>
 </scene>
```

Another one:

```
<scene>
 <episode></episode>
 <season></season>
 <episode></episode>
 </scene>
```

So the idea here is allowing `episodes` and `seasons` in `<scene>` (with unbounded limits). And if these two elements (seasons and episodes) doesn't exist you can use `<part>` element inside `<scene>` with unbounded limits.

I'm trying to do this in XML Schema. I tried groups and complexContent without success. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us what you already have. It will help with the answers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use compound `xs:choice` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="scene">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="part" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="episode"/>
          <xs:element name="season"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

This says that `scene` can consist of either an unbounded number of `part` elements or an unbounded mix of `episode` and `season` elements.

Comment: does that ensure, though, that the elements are mutex ?

Comment: @theRiley: There exists mutual exclusion between the `part` elements and an unbounded mix of `episode` and `season` elements, yes, but not between `episode` and `season` because of the `maxOccurs="unbounded` on `xs:choice` wrapping those elements.